# How to search for data in this format of beautiful soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was using beautiful soup to read the html file of a LinkedIn webpage but I don't understand how to search in that file format. I only used it with html files before and I am confused how to search for the details I need. I attached an image of the text I am getting.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuStD.png)

Comment: Looks link JSON. Take look at [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

It is returning a dictionary. It can be read using the keys that it has. just like html it will use strings as keys. You just need to find the path and use the format:
`dictionary[key][key][key]` to get the value you desire